# Untrappable COMException with GetRefTypeInfo

Tags: c#, interface, com, com-interop

I have a function whose role is to return the name of a COM type; it works fine on x64, but crashes in the middle of iterating the COM types in the Excel type library (and MS-Project too, ..and probably other ones I'm not aware of), and I can't seem to be able to do anything to `catch` the exception it's throwing.

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
>   Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

This results in an `AccessViolationException`, which results in *sudden death* for the EXCEL.EXE host process.

I was able to add some debug output and identify exactly which member was blowing up:

> - Querying AsTypeName for member SheetPivotTableBeforeDiscardChanges
> - Member EXCEL.EXE;**Excel.IAppEvents.SheetPivotTableBeforeDiscardChanges**
>     (Object) added successfully
> - Querying AsTypeName for parameter Sh
> - Parameter EXCEL.EXE;Excel.IAppEvents.Sh (Object) added successfully
> - Querying AsTypeName for **parameter TargetPivotTable**

When the Excel type library starts loading, the entire VBA type library has successfully loaded. If I run my process in a MS-Word host, everything runs fine, so it looks like there's *something* about the type of the `TargetPivotTable` parameter of `IAppEvents.SheetPivotTableBeforeDiscardChanges` that doesn't like what I've written to query it.

```
case VarEnum.VT_USERDEFINED:
    int href;
    unchecked
    {
        if (Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (IntPtr)) == sizeof (long))
        {
            href = (int) desc.lpValue.ToInt64();
        }
        else
        {
            href = desc.lpValue.ToInt32();
        }
    }
    ITypeInfo refTypeInfo;
    info.GetRefTypeInfo(href, out refTypeInfo); // <~ boom
    return GetTypeName(refTypeInfo);
```

Here's the relevant part of the stack trace a contributor was able to get from a MS-Project host:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.ITypeInfo.GetRefTypeInfo(Int32 hRef, ITypeInfo& ppTI)
at Rubberduck.Parsing.Symbols.ReferencedDeclarationsCollector.GetTypeName(TYPEDESC desc, ITypeInfo info) in c:\Users\Andrew\Documents\GitHub\Rubberduck\Rubberduck.Parsing\Symbols\ReferencedDeclarationsCollector.cs:line 95
at Rubberduck.Parsing.Symbols.ReferencedDeclarationsCollector.GetTypeName(TYPEDESC desc, ITypeInfo info) in c:\Users\Andrew\Documents\GitHub\Rubberduck\Rubberduck.Parsing\Symbols\ReferencedDeclarationsCollector.cs:line 89
at Rubberduck.Parsing.Symbols.ReferencedDeclarationsCollector.CreateFieldDeclaration(ITypeInfo info, Int32 fieldIndex, DeclarationType typeDeclarationType, QualifiedModuleName typeQualifiedModuleName, Declaration moduleDeclaration)
```

The code gets a `VT_PTR`, so it gets a `TYPEDESC` out of that pointer (line 89), and then recurses; the same code then gets a `VT_USERDEFINED`, so it gets an `ITypeInfo` out of the `lpValue` of the `TYPEDESC` (line 95), and *normally* I get that `ITypeInfo` and fetch the type's name. For some reason in a 32-bit context `GetRefTypeInfo` refuses to cooperate and sends everything into flames.

---

For full context, here's the entire relevant code:

```
private string GetTypeName(TYPEDESC desc, ITypeInfo info)
{
    var vt = (VarEnum)desc.vt;
    TYPEDESC tdesc;

    switch (vt)
    {
        case VarEnum.VT_PTR:
            tdesc = (TYPEDESC)Marshal.PtrToStructure(desc.lpValue, typeof(TYPEDESC));
            return GetTypeName(tdesc, info);
        case VarEnum.VT_USERDEFINED:
            int href;
            unchecked
            {
                if (Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (IntPtr)) == sizeof (long))
                {
                    href = (int) desc.lpValue.ToInt64();
                }
                else
                {
                    href = desc.lpValue.ToInt32();
                }
            }
            ITypeInfo refTypeInfo;
            info.GetRefTypeInfo(href, out refTypeInfo);
            return GetTypeName(refTypeInfo);
        case VarEnum.VT_CARRAY:
            tdesc = (TYPEDESC)Marshal.PtrToStructure(desc.lpValue, typeof(TYPEDESC));
            return GetTypeName(tdesc, info) + "()";
        default:
            string result;
            if (TypeNames.TryGetValue(vt, out result))
            {
                return result;
            }
            break;
    }
    return "Object";
}

private string GetTypeName(ITypeInfo info)
{
    string typeName;
    string docString; // todo: put the docString to good use?
    int helpContext;
    string helpFile;
    info.GetDocumentation(-1, out typeName, out docString, out helpContext, out helpFile);

    return typeName;
}
```

Is there anything in that `switch` block that looks like it's waiting to blow up in a 32-bit context?

Comment: E_FAIL could mean anything, it is merely a teacher's grade for the quality of the error reporting.  If it actually means "oops, I just corrupted the dickens out of the heap" as it appears to do in this case then you will need Microsoft Support to get ahead.

Comment: If I understand right, TYPEDESC is a union, and the first 32 bits contain an HREFTYPE if vt is VT_USERDEFINED.  So I don't understand why you're taking 64 bits (des.lpValue) and casting to int rather than just taking the first 32 bits.  I.e. desc.lpValue.ToInt64() & 0xFFFFFFFF

Comment: @Joe `href = (int)(desc.lpValue.ToInt64() & 0xFFFFFFFF);` still throws the same exception... or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @HansPassant we've investigated further, and got an HRESULT: 0x0x80004003 = E_POINTER = Invalid pointer. In other words the `href` pointer I'm giving `GetRefTypeInfo` is somehow invalid. Is that what "corrupting the dickens out of the heap" means?

Comment: Seeing the program fall over with an access violation exception next is what the dickens means.  If you now suddenly get E_POINTER then that can also be a side effect of the dickens.

Comment: @HansPassant so, we circumvented the problem by returning a fallback `"Object"` string when `IsBadReadPtr` (Kernel32 DllImport) returns `true`. Sending these occurrences to the debug output, there's 4 bad pointers in the Excel type library (repro'd with another contributor in a VM). The VBE object browser is apparently able to read them, so we're still puzzled with *why* we're getting these bad pointers, but at least it doesn't blow up in 32-bit Excel anymore. =)